# Racket saves image variable as image to disk

Tags: image, racket

In racket, I can define an image variable like this:

```
(define a [img])
```

But would it be possible to store this image to disk? I know that I insert the image from my disk, but I am wondering would it be possible to store it back to disk in program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `save-image`:

http://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpimage.html?q=save-image#%28def._%28%28lib._2htdp%2Fimage..rkt%29._save-image%29%29

(save-image a "image of arrow.png")

Comment: Just  `a` in the REPL.

Comment: Thanks again. I read the document, and it seems there is no method to display a bitmap object?

Comment: What do you mean by "display a bitmap object"? If you write (display a) then the image is displayed.